# ParseObject getString() returns null for Pointer column

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have something like this

```
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MyTable");
    query.include("tag");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject objects : objectList) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "parse object name : " + objects.getString("name"));
                    Log.d(TAG, "tag name : " + objects.getString("tag"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

for each row, I have columns like `String name` and `Pointer<Tag>`.

[image]

In LogCat, it prints out names correctly, but it prints out `null` for each tag.

```
parse object name : Events
tag name : null
```

I don't actually need to get pointer, but all I need is to get the tag in String format (I can't modify the table to make the column String now).

What can I do to be able to get the Pointer as String format?

Comment: u cant to fetch like on this way pointer as a string is not possible in parse database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this to get value from pointer.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("MyTable");
query.include("tag");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    public void done(List<ParseObject> objectList, ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            for(ParseObject objects : objectList) {
                Log.d(TAG, "parse object name : " + objects.getString("name"));


                ParseObject tagObject=objects.getParseObject("tag");
                //Now access your tag class column
                Log.d(TAG, "tag name : " + tagObject.getString("columnName"));

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dreamed about it because I was thinking so hard overnight. All of a sudden the purpose of the pointer made all sense, and looking at this answer made everything clearer. It's working like a charm. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try on this line code for `log`

```
 Log.e(TAG, "tag name : " + objects.getParseObject("tag").getString("col_name");
```

this way to fetch `parse pointer object`.

Answer (score -1):

To read value of a pointer,read it as a parse object.

```
 Log.d(TAG, "tag name : " + objects.getParseObject("tag"));
```

**Note**: When you are doing your query you must to include the pointer field if you want to be able to extract the data from it after the query will be returned. The result:

```
query.include("pointer_filed");
```

Comment: -1 because this one will print out the object id (not objectId from Parse, but from java). Also second half of your answer is a direct copy from someone else's answer. :p